# Garbage values in lambda-captured variables as callback

Tags: c++, lambda

I know that this may be fairly confusing, but I'm writing a unit test using the Boost test framework. I'm trying to simply increment a variable to test that a specific callback was executed as expected.

This is the test code excerpt:

```
  uint32_t nSuccessCallbacks = 0;
  uint32_t nFailureCallbacks = 0;
  auto successCallback = [&nSuccessCallbacks, this] {
    std::cout << "Running success callback...\n";
    ++nSuccessCallbacks;
  };

  auto failureCallback = [&nFailureCallbacks, this] (const std::string& str) {
    std::cout << "Error code: " << str << "\n";
    std::cout << "Running failure callback...\n";
    ++nFailureCallbacks;
  };

  dest.advertise(rr, successCallback, failureCallback);
```

The definition of `advertise`:

```
void
NfdRibReadvertiseDestination::advertise(nfd::rib::ReadvertisedRoute& rr,
                                        std::function<void()> successCb,
                                        std::function<void(const std::string&)> failureCb)
{
  m_controller.start<ndn::nfd::RibRegisterCommand>(
    ControlParameters().setName(rr.getPrefix()).setOrigin(ndn::nfd::ROUTE_ORIGIN_CLIENT).setFlags(ndn::nfd::ROUTE_FLAG_CHILD_INHERIT),
    [&] (const ControlParameters& cp) { successCb(); },
    [&] (const ControlResponse& cr) { failureCb(cr.getText()); });
}
```

Just for reference, `dest` is defined in the test fixture.

I'm not able to modify `nSuccessCallbacks`. Whenever the callback is called, we step through it correctly, but after the callback exits and we are in code after `dest.advertise()`, the value is still 0. We successfully reach the callback lambda, but the gdb reports that there is no such variable in the scope. I've tried every reasonable combination of all-capture, specific capture, mixing in the `this` and removing it, etc. I don't know why the capture clause incorrectly captures the variable. My best guess is that since the lambda is passed into another lambda, the capture clause of the first is lost?

**EDIT**: The callback is executed when an interface object receives data. We mock that up later in the test, and was unimportant so I chose not to include it.

Comment: And we are supposed to ask our crystal balls for the specific problem?

Comment: No, the captures are not "lost". They are captured by reference. This means that when the lambdas are executed, those counters better still be in the scope. If they were already destroyed, hello undefined behavior!

Comment: You did not describe how you know it captures garbage.  The above code never runs the lambda, so it cannot illustrate such an event.  The problem thus occurs somewhere else, which you did not share.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That is a consideration that we have in the unit tests. We have a method `advanceClocks` that essentially runs out time waiting for these callbacks to execute.

@Yakk It in fact does execute, because I set a breakpoint in the callback and then ran the test in GDB. We reach the callback, even do the increment, but the values are impermanent.

Comment: @Bronze It doesn't execute in the code you posted.  It executes somewhere else.  Maybe in start.  Maybe after the code you posted.  But copy/paste the above code and stub every interface whose implementation you did not include and no lambda would run.  The **actual point where the problem occurs** is important.  A [MCVE] is important.  [MCVE] is there because *if you don't know what went wrong, you cannot know what is not important* -- a MCVE guarantees your minimal example actually includes enough info to demonstrate your problem!

Comment: gdb isn't perfect. It does, sometimes, get confused when it's trying to unravel lambdas, etc..., on the call stack. I don't always trust it, so when faced with dubious output, I explicitly dump the variables in question, to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Using a crystal ball, your lambda is run after one of the many scopes where you capture something by reference (either `advertise` or your "test code exerpt") has exited.  Thus the by-reference captured variable has left scope, and UB results, and you see garbage.

Your code as posted does not actually run the lambda, so clearly the code as posted has no such problem with the lambda containing garbage.

As a general rule, never capture by reference if your lambda or any copies of it could possibly outlive the current scope.  Capture by copy, or (in C++14) by move.  There are exceptions to this rule, but they are easy sources of bugs.

As a second rule, if your lambda outlives the current scope, explicitly capture everything you capture.  Have no default capture.  That way you won't be surprised by something being captured whose lifetime (or pointed-to lifetime) is not long enough, like `this` or some pointer or somesuch.

At the least do this:

```
[successCb] (const ControlParameters& cp) { successCb(); },
[failureCb] (const ControlResponse& cr) { failureCb(cr.getText()); }
```

Then ensure that this, and no copies of this:

```
auto successCallback = [&nSuccessCallbacks, this] {
  std::cout << "Running success callback...\n";
  ++nSuccessCallbacks;
};
```

does not outlive its scope.  If it does, change how you capture.

Comment: With all due respect, this does look like a comment more than an answer...

Comment: @SergeyA I'd give 10:1 odds that the crystal ball is accurate.  The OP's problem is capture by reference, and the lambda outlasting the scope of captured variables.  I cannot be certain, hence crystal ball.

Comment: I agree. However, i believe in properly formulated questions :)

Comment: I too think that it is because of capture by reference. I'm merely aping the procedure taken in other (seemingly) similar unit tests. I am considering using bind to avoid capture by reference altogether.

Comment: @Bronze Why `bind`?  List your captures explicitly in a lambda capture list.  Never use `[&]` unless you know the lambda produced and all of its copies will be gone before your current scope ends.

Comment: Because I'm totally lost and don't understand what the matter is, and I'm now grasping in random directions hoping for something to change.

Comment: @bronze it may help to know what `[&]` does.  Do you know?

Comment: AFAIK it captures any mentioned variable within the lambda body by reference, meaning that those captures are subject to lifetime problems.

Comment: @Bronze Your `[&] (const ControlParameters& cp) { successCb(); }` lambdas have copies that exceed the scope they are in.  `successCb` is captured by-reference, but is gone by the time the lambda is called.

Comment: Is it? Why would successCb be captured by reference when it is passed to the function as an argument? Is it possible that because the parameter type of the successCallback is a std::function<void()>, the compiler is erasing the captures? I know that capturing lambdas cannot be wrapped into a std::function.
EDIT: I was clearly misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @Yakk Changing the capture type of the lambdas in advertise to by-value fixes this problem. Why is this?
If the problem is that the lambda as `successCb` is out of scope when called, why does it call at all? I would imagine that since the lambda has expired, it should not call anything, not just lose the references. Why does capturing the lambda by value (thus implicitly preserving the references-to-variables it has?) keep the capture list of the lambda from expiring?

Comment: @Bronze I just asked you **what does `[&]` do**.  You use `[&]`.  You told it to capture by reference.  That is why it captures by reference.  You told it to do it.  To **quote you**: "`[&]` captures any mentioned variable within the lambda body by reference, meaning that those captures are subject to lifetime problems."  `successCb` is a variable.  You capture it.  This capture is by reference. The capture exceeds the lifetime of the variable. The problem results. By reference capture is not safe beyond the lifetime of any variable mentioned. Capturing by value does not capture by reference.

Answer (score 1):

The `start` call will, given the name, start an asynchronous thread to process the request. Unfortunately this means that the variables captured by reference in the lambda will have been already deallocated when they're accessed.

C++ only allows you to capture by copy (and you've no lifetime problems) or to capture by reference but you must ensure that the lambda will not outlive the referenced variables.

To solve correctly the "upward funarg" problem (a lambda capturing a variable - not a value - from a context and outliving the context) a garbage collector is needed (a stack isn't enough) and C++ doesn't provide one.

A solution (if you pay attention to avoiding loops) is to capture by value a `shared_ptr` to the mutable shared state needed.